# How to parse tuple, integer, and string in erlang binary?

Tags: binary, erlang

I want to put ip address, port number and custom content in the binary, do binary matching for integers, but I can't find a way to do it.

Assume the ip address is `IP = {192,168,1,1}`, port number is `PN = 10000`, and custom content is `Content = <<"{request, {M, F, A}}">>`, I can put them all into binary by using `Bin = <<list_to_binary(tuple_to_list(IP))/binary, Content/binary, PN/integer>>`, the binary result is

```
<<127,0,0,1,123,114,101,113,117,101,115,116,44,32,123,77,
  44,32,70,44,32,65,125,125,16>>
```

But when I try to do binary matching for the port number(PN), it turns to something else (16), how can I deal with the integer and keep its size to 1 in the binary?

The binary matching is: `<<A:4/binary, B:20/binary, C>> = Bin`. The result of C is 16, not 10000.

Another problem I want to ask is how to limit the size of packet? Is it possible to limit the packet size without concerning the length of content within it? Compromise or chop it into several pieces?

Comment: I see various things here.The code posted does not match with the binary generated. But anyway, How do you know that `Content` is 20 bytes? Among other things, I believe,  that's what you are matching.

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga Thanks, I've noticed the problem and edit the content again. I know the Content is 20 bytes by using byte_size(Content).

Comment: I want to do matching for the integer (port number), but the result is different.

Comment: "and keep its size to 1 in the binary" you want to store the number `10000` in 1 byte or am I misunderstanding this sentence?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, I want to store 10000 in 1 byte, if I use integer_to_binary(), then the length of it will be out of control.

Comment: Well that number is 14 bits long. 1 byte can only store the values 0 to 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need at least 14 bits to represent the number 10000. One way to do this would be:

```
Bin = << IPBin/binary, Content/binary, PN:14/integer-unit:1>>.
```

Which will result in the binary:

```
<<192,168,1,1,123,114,101,113,117,101,115,116,44,32,123,
77,44,32,70,44,32,65,125,125,156,16:6>>
```

It can then be matched as follows:

```
<<A:4/binary, B:20/binary, C:14/integer-unit:1>> = Bin.
```

Hope this sheds some light on [Segments for bit syntax](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html#id66336)

Note: You will need 2 bytes the represent any port number so `PN:16/integer` or `PN:16/unsigned` will be better.

Answer (score 1):

If the port number it's the last part of the binary and the size of everything else it's known, you could use `integer_to_binary(PN)` and attach this value to the binary.

You would then have to use `binary_to_integer(C)` for the reverse, ones C is extracted by pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

```
3> IP = {192,168,1,1}, PN = 10000, Content = <<"{request, {M, F, A}}">>.
<<"{request, {M, F, A}}">>
4> Encode = fun({A, B, C, D}, PN, Content) -> <<A, B, C, D, PN:16/unsigned, Content/bytes>> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.18.50752066>
5> Decode = fun(<<A, B, C, D, PN:16/unsigned, Content/bytes>>) -> {{A, B, C, D}, PN, Content} end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.50752066>
6> V = Encode(IP, PN, Content).
<<192,168,1,1,39,16,123,114,101,113,117,101,115,116,44,32,
  123,77,44,32,70,44,32,65,125,125>>
7> Decode(V).
{{192,168,1,1},10000,<<"{request, {M, F, A}}">>}
```